# error unable to cast COM Object of type 'CtrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ReportSourceClass' to interface

Tags: vb.net

when I run the application on my computer, the application is running properly. but when the same program runs on another computer, the error appears as shown below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYD3i.png)

Comment: Thanks for your statement. What is your question?

Comment: Two basic explanations for this exception.  Most commonly it is caused by a version mismatch with the installed version of the COM component.  Could be a broken install, not very common.  Either way you'll have to run the proper Crystal Reports installer on the target machine.